# What does a copy constructor actually do?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I am new to c++ programming and I am stuck at a part where both the members show the same value.. Can you guys explain why? Thx in advance.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class test{
  public:
    int all,sum;

    test(int x){
        all=x;
    }

    test(test &a){
        all=a.all+5;
        cout<<all;   
    }

    void one(test m){
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<m.all;
        cout<<endl<<all;
    }
};

int main(){
    test a(10),b(a);
    b.one(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really need to learn how to properly format your code. Also I'd suggest only one declaration/initialization per line, instead of multiple variables.

Comment: A copy constructor can do whatever you want it to do.  Usually, members are copied from another object to *this* object.

Comment: A *debugger* would help you answer this question faster than posting to StackOverflow and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that both `a` and `b` have the same value.  Because they don't.  A debugger would have shown you that `a.all` is 10 and `b.all` is 15, as expected.

The real problem is that you are passing `a` to `one()` **by value**, so the compiler has to make a **temporary copy** of `a`.  That means the compiler will copy-construct `m` using your copy constructor (and will destroy `m` when `one()` exits).  As such, the `m.all` value is always an incremented-by-5 value, never the original value.

In your example, the value of `b.all` and `m.all` just *happen* to be the same value, only because they are both copy-constructed from the same `a` object.  Try passing `b` to `one()` instead (`b.one(b);`) and you will see that `m.all` will be 20 instead of 15.

To solve your issue, you need to change `one()` to take its `m` parameter **by reference** instead:

```
void one(const test &m) {
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<m.all;
    cout<<endl<<all;
}
```

That way, no temporary copy is needed.  Passing `a` to `one()` will output `a.all` as-is, as expected.  Passing `b` to `one()` will output `b.all` as-is, as expected.  And so on.

---

Also, on a side note, your copy constructor should be taking its `a` parameter by **const** reference as well:

```
test(const test &a){
    all=a.all+5;
    cout<<all;   
}
```

Comment: Thx! But could you also explain me how the values become equal in detail? I really couldn't understand this part. What happens when b.one(a) is called?